# Corona Runtime error on collision

Tags: coronasdk, game-physics

Getting stuck in a code I am playing around with. I am getting run time scene_game.lua:290: attempt to call method 'removeEventListener' (a nil value) error. 290 is referring to this part of the code

```
for i=1,#lanes do
                lanes[i]:removeEventListener("touch", moveCar)
            end
```

The funny part is this error does not get invoked when the collision in

```
elseif (self=="enemy" and other=="player") then
```

Rather, it only gets invoked when this part of the code shown below gets executed.

```
elseif (self=="player" and other=="enemy") then
```

The whole section of the code is provided below for Your reference. Pls help!

```
function scene:create( event )

    -- Initialize the scene here.
    -- Example: add display objects to "sceneGroup", add touch listeners, etc.
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- The following variables are known as forward declares. We'll create some for the player, enemy, lanes and establish default values.
    local lanes = {} -- create a table called lanes
    local playerCar -- a variable for the player car
    local playerCar1 -- a variable for the player car
    local sprite
    local laneID = 1 -- a variable for the land id
    local enemyCars = {} -- a table to hold the enemy cars
    local enemyCounter = 1 -- start the enemy counter at 1 to keep track of the enemy cars

    local sendEnemyFrequency = 2500 -- defines how often to send enemy cars
    local tmrToSendCars -- a variable to hold a reference to the timer of sending cars    

    local playerScore = 0 -- start the player score at 0
    local playerScoreText -- an object to hold the score text object

    -- This function will increment the player score by 1. This function is called when the transition for the enemy car is complete and is off screen.

    local sheetInfo = require("zo")
        local myImageSheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "zo.png", sheetInfo:getSheet() )


local sequenceData = {
    {
    name="walk",                                  -- name of the animation
    sheet=myImageSheet,                           -- the image sheet
    start=sheetInfo:getFrameIndex("1"), -- first frame
    count=4,                                      -- number of frames
    time=700,                                    -- speed
    loopCount=0                                   -- repeat
    }
}

    local sheetInfo2 = require("opo")
        local myImageSheet2 = graphics.newImageSheet( "opo.png", sheetInfo2:getSheet() )


local sequenceData2 = {
    {
    name="walk2",                                  -- name of the animation
    sheet=myImageSheet,                           -- the image sheet
    start=sheetInfo:getFrameIndex("1"), -- first frame
    count=4,                                      -- number of frames
    time=700,                                    -- speed
    loopCount=0                                   -- repeat
    }
}





    chk=0
        function messenger2(text)
        if chk==0 then
g4A = display.newGroup()
halt1= display.newRect( -30 , 150, 50+100*9, 44*2+30-65 )
halt1.alpha=.85
halt1.anchorX=0
halt1.anchorY=0
halt1:setFillColor( .2, .2, .2 ,.95)
halt1:setStrokeColor( .8, .8 ,.8 )
halt1.strokeWidth = .51
audio.play(levelup)
halt1text = display.newText( text, 235, 44*3+185-140,native.systemFont, 26 )
halt1text:setFillColor( .8, .8, .8 )

 g4A:insert( halt1 ) 
  g4A:insert( halt1text )

   transition.fadeOut( g4A, { time=2500, transition=easing.inCirc  } )
    sceneGroup:insert(g4A) 
end
end


    local function incrementScore()
        playerScore = playerScore + 1 -- add playerScore by 1
        playerScoreText.text = "Score: "..playerScore -- update the on screen text



        if playerScore>bestscore then
    bestscore=playerScore

    messenger2("New high score reached")
    chk=1
     loadsave.saveTable(bestscore, "Bestscorenow.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    end




    end

    -- moveCar will respond to the touch event on the lanes
    local function moveCar(event)

        if(event.phase == "ended") then 

            laneID = event.target.id -- grab the lane id which will be 1, 2, or 3
            transition.to(playerCar, {x=lanes[laneID].x,time=50}) -- move the player car to the appropriate lane
            transition.to(playerCar1, {x=lanes[laneID].x,time=50}) -- move the player car to the appropriate lane
            transition.to(sprite, {x=lanes[laneID].x,time=50}) -- move the player car to the appropriate lane

audio.play(movingck)

            return true -- to indicate a successful touch event, return true
        end
    end





    -- sendEnemyCar is where the magic happens. This function will send enemy cars from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen.
    local function sendEnemyCar()
    if(enemyCounter%7 == 0) then
    enemyCars[enemyCounter] =   display.newImageRect(sceneGroup, "tr.png", 20, 20)
    enemyCars[enemyCounter].x = lanes[math.random(1,#lanes)].x -- place the car on a random lane
            if(math.random(1,2) == 1) then enemyCars[enemyCounter].x = lanes[laneID].x; end -- 50% of the time, place the enemy car on the player car lane. 
        enemyCars[enemyCounter].y = -125 -- place the enemy off screen at the top
        enemyCars[enemyCounter]:scale(1.8,-1.65) -- rotate the cars so they are facing down
        physics.addBody(enemyCars[enemyCounter]) -- add a physics body to enemy cars
        enemyCars[enemyCounter].bodyType = "kinematic" -- make the bodies kinematic
        enemyCars[enemyCounter].id = "trophy" -- id

        transition.to(enemyCars[enemyCounter], {y=display.contentHeight+enemyCars[enemyCounter].height+20, time=math.random(2250,3000), onComplete=function(self) display.remove(self); incrementScore(); end}) -- a transition that moves the enemy car towards the bottom of the screen. On completion, the enemy car object is removed from the game.

        enemyCounter = enemyCounter + 1 -- increase enemy counter by one for tracking
        if(enemyCounter%2 == 0) then -- every other car, increase the speed of enemy frequency
            sendEnemyFrequency = sendEnemyFrequency - 200 -- deduct the frequency by 200ms
            if(sendEnemyFrequency < 850) then sendEnemyFrequency = 850; end -- cap the send enemy frequency to 800
            timer.cancel(tmrToSendCars) -- cancel the timer of sending cars
            tmrToSendCars = timer.performWithDelay(sendEnemyFrequency, sendEnemyCar, 0) -- recreate the time to send cars with update frequency
        end
    else
        enemyCars[enemyCounter] =   display.newSprite(sceneGroup, myImageSheet2, sequenceData2 )
enemyCars[enemyCounter]:setSequence("walk2")
enemyCars[enemyCounter]:play()

        enemyCars[enemyCounter].x = lanes[math.random(1,#lanes)].x -- place the car on a random lane
            if(math.random(1,2) == 1) then enemyCars[enemyCounter].x = lanes[laneID].x; end -- 50% of the time, place the enemy car on the player car lane. 
        enemyCars[enemyCounter].y = -125 -- place the enemy off screen at the top
        enemyCars[enemyCounter]:scale(1.8,-1.65) -- rotate the cars so they are facing down
        local offsetRectParams = { halfWidth=20, halfHeight=20, x=0, y=60, angle=0 }

        physics.addBody(enemyCars[enemyCounter], { box=offsetRectParams } ) -- add a physics body to enemy cars
        enemyCars[enemyCounter].bodyType = "kinematic" -- make the bodies kinematic
        enemyCars[enemyCounter].id = "enemy" -- id

        transition.to(enemyCars[enemyCounter], {y=display.contentHeight+enemyCars[enemyCounter].height+20, time=math.random(2250,3000), onComplete=function(self) display.remove(self); incrementScore(); end}) -- a transition that moves the enemy car towards the bottom of the screen. On completion, the enemy car object is removed from the game.

        enemyCounter = enemyCounter + 1 -- increase enemy counter by one for tracking
        if(enemyCounter%2 == 0) then -- every other car, increase the speed of enemy frequency
            sendEnemyFrequency = sendEnemyFrequency - 200 -- deduct the frequency by 200ms
            if(sendEnemyFrequency < 850) then sendEnemyFrequency = 850; end -- cap the send enemy frequency to 800
            timer.cancel(tmrToSendCars) -- cancel the timer of sending cars
            tmrToSendCars = timer.performWithDelay(sendEnemyFrequency, sendEnemyCar, 0) -- recreate the time to send cars with update frequency
        end

    end
    end

    -- Allow the player to return to the menu
    local function onPlayAgainTouch()

        composer.gotoScene("scene_menu", "fade") -- move player to menu
    end


    local function playersdead()

         audio.play(deads)
    print(deads)
            -- stop the game
            transition.pause()
            timer.cancel(tmrToSendCars)
            physics.pause()
              playerCar1.isVisible = true
      playerCar.alpha = 0
      sprite.alpha = 0



            -- remove event listeners from all lanes
            for i=1,#lanes do
                lanes[i]:removeEventListener("touch", moveCar)
            end
Runtime:removeEventListener( "collision",onGlobalCollision )
            local gameOverBackground = display.newRect(sceneGroup, 0, 0, display.actualContentWidth, display.actualContentHeight) -- display an opaque background graphic for some game over polish
                gameOverBackground.x = display.contentCenterX
                gameOverBackground.y = display.contentCenterY
                gameOverBackground:setFillColor(0)
                gameOverBackground.alpha = 0.5

            -- Create a text object that will display game over text
            local gameOverText = display.newText( sceneGroup, "Game Over!", 100, 200, native.systemFontBold, 36 )
            gameOverText.x = display.contentCenterX
            gameOverText.y = 150
            gameOverText:setFillColor( 1, 1, 1 )   

 wpmaGlobalAdmob.showAdmobInterstitialAd() 
wpmaGlobalAdmob.loadAdmobInterstitialAd()           

            -- create a button that allows the player to return to the
            local playAgain = widget.newButton {
                width = 220,
                height = 100,
                defaultFile = "images/btn-blank.png",
                overFile = "images/btn-blank.png",        
                label = "Menu",
                font = system.defaultFontBold,
                fontSize = 32,
                labelColor = { default={ 0, 0, 0 }, over={ 0, 0, 0, 0.5 } },
                onEvent = onPlayAgainTouch
            }
            playAgain.x = display.contentCenterX
            playAgain.y = gameOverText.y + 100
            sceneGroup:insert(playAgain)      

    end

    local function trophyz()
      audio.play(uplevel)

    end


    -- This is the global collision scene. There are several ways to handle collisions and this is only one method. I felt this was the easiest for learning purposes.
    local function onGlobalCollision(event)
        if(event.phase == "began") then -- when the enemy car collides into the player car, this if/then statement will be true        
local self = event.object2.id
local other = event.object1.id

        print_r( self)       --the first object in the collision
  print_r( other )       --the second object in the collision
 --   print_r( event.element1 )      --the element (number) of the first object which was hit in the collision
 --   print_r( event.element2 )               

 if (self=="player" and other=="trophy") then

 event.object1:removeSelf()
trophyz()
 elseif (self=="trophy" and other=="player") then

  event.object2:removeSelf()
 trophyz()
 elseif (self=="player" and other=="enemy") then
  playersdead()
 print("Someting screwy here")
 elseif (self=="enemy" and other=="player") then
  playersdead()


    --display.remove(self)
 else
 print("U SHOULD NOT BE HERE")

        end





         --END COLLISION  
    end
        end


    local background = display.newImageRect(sceneGroup, "images/background.png", 475, 713) -- create the background image object
        background.x = display.contentCenterX -- place the graphic in the center of the x-axis
        background.y = display.contentCenterY -- place the graphic in the center of the y-axis

    for i=1,3 do -- loop 3 times to create 3 lanes for our game
        lanes[i] = display.newImageRect(sceneGroup, "images/lane.png", 79, 713)
            lanes[i].x = (display.contentCenterX - 79*2) + (i*80)
            lanes[i].y = display.contentCenterY
            lanes[i].id = i
            lanes[i]:addEventListener("touch", moveCar) -- add an event listener to the lanes that will respond to touch events.
    end

    playerScoreText = display.newText(sceneGroup, "Score: "..playerScore, 0, 0, native.systemFont, 36) -- Create a text object that will display the player score
        playerScoreText.x = display.contentCenterX
        playerScoreText.y = 25






    playerCar = display.newImageRect(sceneGroup, "images/playerCar.png", 60, 60) -- create the player car image object
        playerCar.anchorY = 1 -- set the anchor point to 1 which is the bottom of the graphic
        playerCar.x = lanes[1].x -- put the player car on the first lane
        playerCar.y = display.contentHeight-70 -- place the car at the bottom of the screen
        physics.addBody(playerCar) -- add a physics body to the car
        playerCar.bodyType = "dynamic" -- make the car a dynamic body type
            playerCar.id = "player" 

        playerCar1 = display.newImageRect(sceneGroup, "images/playerCar11.png", 50, 100) -- create the player car image object
        playerCar1.anchorY = 1 -- set the anchor point to 1 which is the bottom of the graphic
        playerCar1.x = lanes[1].x -- put the player car on the first lane
        playerCar1.y = display.contentHeight -- place the car at the bottom of the screen
     -- id

      --    physics.addBody(playerCar1) -- add a physics body to the car
      --    playerCar1.bodyType = "dynamic" -- make the car a dynamic body type



sprite = display.newSprite( myImageSheet, sequenceData )
sprite:scale( 1.6, 1.6)
sprite.anchorY = 1
sprite:setSequence("walk")
sprite:play()

sprite.x = lanes[1].x -- put the player car on the first lane
        sprite.y = display.contentHeight -- place the car at the bottom of the screen




      playerCar1.isVisible = false
      playerCar.isVisible = true

        playerCar.alpha = 0

    tmrToSendCars = timer.performWithDelay(sendEnemyFrequency, sendEnemyCar, 0) -- start a timer to send cards. A 0 means run forever
    Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onGlobalCollision ) -- create a global event listener to listen for any collision.

end
```

Comment: The formatting of your code makes it much harder to read and, hence, debug.  It would be worthwhile to making a tabs and spacing consistent.

Comment: Please extract a [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

To start with, `self` is a reserved word, so you probably don't want to be declaring it as a `local` in `onGlobalCollision()`.  For example, `obj1` and `obj2` would do.

In the loop where you execute `lanes[i]:removeEventListener("touch", moveCar)`, what (if anything) **is** defined in the table `lanes[i]`?  You could find out by doing:

```
for k,v in pairs(lanes[i]) do
    print(k,v)
end
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply... I tried to run the step you suggested...when the collision is between enemy and player then the table is ok...the code is fine ...However, when the collision is between player and enemy ...the table is incomplete....I have added another answer below to show the details

Comment: This below is the incomplete table of lanes that is generated: 22:24:45.147    player
22:24:45.147    enemy
22:24:45.147  userdata: 06D698B8
22:24:45.147  table: 0CD0A920 {
22:24:45.147    [id] => 3
22:24:45.147    [_functionListeners] => table: 0CD0A920 {
22:24:45.147                              [touch] => table: 0CD0AA10 {
22:24:45.147                                           [1] => function: 06D19088
22:24:45.147                                         }
22:24:45.147                            }
22:24:45.147  }